# Gradle 7.0 Bitbucket artifactory

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish

I have been trying to use bitbucket as maven artifactory. Since Gradle 7 the uploadarchives as deprecated and replaced with maven_publish with publish method. The methods no longer compatible with wagonGit. Does any try to use Bitbucket with Gradle 7?. I couldnt find out a way to push my artifactory any help would be greatly appreciated